# Determining $A$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to\infty }(\sqrt{Ax^2+2x}−5x)$ exists and is finite

Tags: calculus, limits

> Determine the value of the real number $A$ so that a finite limit exists, and then compute the limit:
> $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}(\sqrt{Ax^2+2x}−5x)$$

Where would I start with this? I thought I could factor the highest degree variable from each term but that lets any real A work with it.

Comment: Pull out $\sqrt A x$ and see what happens.

Comment: $A=25{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The $2x$ term would be of little consequence in the convergence of the limit, so to find $A$, you can discard the $2x$ term.

Comment: Hint: $$
\sqrt {Ax^2  + 2x}  - 5x = \frac{{(A - 25)x^2  + 2x}}{{\sqrt {Ax^2  + 2x}  + 5x}}  \;\left( { \sim \frac{{(A - 25)x + 2}}{{\sqrt A  + 5}}} \right)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{aligned} \sqrt{Ax^2+2x}-5x &= (\sqrt{Ax^2+2x}-5x)\frac{\sqrt{Ax^2+2x}+5x}{\sqrt{Ax^2+2x}+5x}\\ &= \frac{Ax^2+2x-25x^2}{\sqrt{Ax^2+2x}+5x}\\ &= \frac{(A-25)x+2}{\sqrt{A+\frac{2}{x}}+5} \end{aligned}$

Notice that, as $x$ goes to $\infty$, the denominator goes to $\sqrt{A}+5$ and the numerator goes to

1. $+\infty$ if $A>25$
2. $-\infty$ if $A<25$
3. $2$ if $A = 25$

so $A=25$ is our only hope to obtain a finite result, which would be

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{25}+5} = \frac{1}{5}$$